# Node JS CLI + Node Library

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface, commonjs, node-modules

I'm working on creating a node library which includes a CLI to work with it.

The full (however not long) code is found at https://github.com/claydiffrient/reltoabs.

Because I'm actively developing this, I'm using a `npm link` to work with in during development.

The portion giving me trouble seems to be in the `cli.js` file.  When I include the module via a `var reltoabs = require('reltoabs')` node spits back an error saying that the `reltoabs` module doesn't exist, however it is in the node_modules.  Any idea how I can make this work?

Comment: Try:    var reltoabs = require('app/reltoabs');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the module you're trying to require isn't a native module and doesn't start with a path identifier, then Node will start by looking in the parent directory of the current module and appends `/node_modules`. Node will then look in that directory, and if the module isn't there, then it will iterate up the filesystem tree until the root is reached.

Assuming you're developing from a modules folder, your require does these searches:

```
/module/path/lib/node_modules/reltoabs
/path/lib/node_modules/reltoabs
/lib/node_modules/reltoabs
```

This doesn't explain the error you're getting, but to avoid errors like yours, references files relatively when possible:

```
var reltoabs = require('./reltoabs')
```

Comment: Actually that seemed to fix the problem!  Thanks so much!